# How to recognize part of the picture by program?

Tags: image-processing

for example I have a `banana` picture and I know there is a lot of way to recognize the `whole` picture by program, but what should I do in the situation that only part of the `banana` picture is showed. How to recognize it ?

I know little about `image recognization`, how should I start, I can't find the relative info on the `web`. And I join a `image recognization` group a member of it tell me that is not a easy task.

How should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some open source projects, where you can get a "start point" or an idea...

[Similar Images finder](http://similarimagesfinder.codeplex.com/)
[Shape recognition](https://leakingmemory.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/shape-recognition-using-c-and-aforge/)

Microsoft als offer very interesting services, but the code isn't available, but it's worth to have a look:

[Microsoft Cognitive Services](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api)

I also think it's not an easy task.